# What files/code should I look for iOS Coinbase Wallet Seed Phrase?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, coinbase-transaction, recover-private-key, ios

I never wrote down my seed phrase for Coinbase wallet and used FaceId to Login for months. One day the app did an update which forced me off the app and prompted me for the seed phrase to login.

I have had a forensics data company extract my phone data and I have cellbrite software to search the files. What should I be looking for? What language? Do I need to convert it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

You need that "seed phrase". Without it, your money is gone. You won't find the seed phrase in your phone.

---

Coinbase claim this is a non-custodial wallet. If it works like others, the seed phrase (also known as a recovery phrase or backup phrase) is not stored on your IOS device and cannot be recoverd from it.

Coinbase's [support pages](https://help.coinbase.com/en/contact-us/support-faq/coinbase-wallet/how-to-recover-access-to-coinbase-wallet) say

> If you no longer have access to your recovery phrase, you will need to create a new account.
>
> Please note: Coinbase Wallet is a user-controlled, non-custodial product. The recovery phrase is what gives you, and only you, access to move funds that you have received.
>
> For your security, Coinbase Wallet will never have access to this seed, meaning that we are unable to move funds on your behalf.

If they have done their job properly, nobody with access to your phone can get access to your money without knowing the recovery phrase (or PIN). That would include you.

---

Another Coinbase [support page](https://help.coinbase.com/en/wallet/managing-account/can-i-lose-access-to-my-wallet-funds) says

> Coinbase Wallet generates a 12-word recovery phrase, also referred to as a seed phrase, that you and only you have access to. This means that **if you lose your recovery phrase, you will lose access to your Coinbase Wallet**. Please keep in mind that Coinbase will never have access to this recovery phrase, so we cannot move funds on your behalf or help you access your digital assets.
>
> **Back up your wallet**
>
> As an added safeguard, we built an encrypted Google Drive and iCloud feature so you can back up your recovery phrase. **We strongly encourage you to back up your recovery phrase using this feature, *as well as* writing it down and storing it in a secure location**. To access the backup feature, tap Settings then Recovery Phrase from your Coinbase Wallet app.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that if you sign out of your Coinbase Wallet mobile app **you will be prompted to acknowledge that signing out without your recovery phrase being backed up may result in permanent loss of access**.

<sup>(my emphasis)</sup>